# Why is the rollback for my transaction not working?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I executed the following code:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pw, $db);
$mysqli->begin_transaction();
try {
    $mysqli->query("Update User SET name='Ginso1' WHERE id=6");
    $mysqli->query("Update Userr SET name='Ginso2' WHERE id=6");
    $mysqli->commit();
} catch(mysqli_sql_exception $exeption) {
    $mysqli->rollback();
    echo "exception";
}
```

Of course, the table Userr does not exist (while User does), so the 2nd query should throw an exception. That seems to work since the echo is executed. But when I check my DB afterwards, I see that the given id's name has been changed to 'Ginso1'. Why is the rollback not working?

I just tried to this directly in phpMyAdmin and the rollback didn't work there either:

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE User SET name='TEST' WHERE id=6;
ROLLBACK;
```

Comment: Have you tried turning autocommit off?

Comment: just tried, no change.(regardless wheter i do it before or after `begin_transaction`

Comment: You said "should" throw an exception. Does it? What happens if you do it without the try/catch in place?

Comment: Is your table InnoDB?

Comment: @Dave yes it does. As i said, the echo statement of the catch-clause is executed

Comment: @Dharman I don't know what that is. How do i find out?

Comment: You can check it in phpMyAdmin. Open the table and got to Operations tab.

Comment: You are right, it is MyISAM. Could there be any reason, why i shouldn't just change it to InnoDB?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your table engine is not InnoDB. As the manual says, to make the transaction work, your database table has to use a transactional engine e.g. InnoDB.

MyISAM is not transactional.

Comment: how can i find out? It's a MySQL database from lima-city.com